# Compare $(x(4-x))/2$ and $(x-4)/(x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's what I've done: [image]

How can I solve the third grade equation? Please try to help me through factorization.

Comment: is the first term $\frac{x(4-x)}{2}$?

Comment: You "simplified" too much. However, even if one does one can hope that the cubic has a rational root. (Most cubics don't, but exercise cubics often do.) The root $x=1$ is easy to spot, else one can use the Rational Roots Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 'pulling out' $4-x$ you have a $x^2 -3x +2$ term in the numerator which collapses to $(x-1)(x-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the expression immediately after finding the common denominator and writing the expression as one quotient. You have $$\frac{(x-3)x(4-x) - 2(x-4)}{2(x-3)} = \frac{x(x-3)(4-x) + 2(4-x)}{2(x-3)}$$

Note that the second term in the numerator was transformed from $-2(x-4)$ to $ +2(4-x),\,$ which then gives us a common factor of $4-x$ in the numerator. $$\frac{(4-x)(x(x-3) + 2)}{ 2(x-3)} = \frac{(4-x)(x^2 - 3x + 2)}{2(x-3)} = \frac{(4-x)(x-1)(x-2)}{2(x-3)}$$

We factored $4-x$ out of the sum in the numerator. The remaining quadratic factors nicely.